# jQuery Form Validation Plugin Default Text

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Hi I am using jQuery Form Validation Plugin
 http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

And I know that the default text is using "*This field is required.*"
And I am wanting to replace it with an IMG tag. But I don't want to change it within the actual PLUGIN, and wondering if it can be done just generically through the plugin options. I have tried many variations but have come up with this cut-down version.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#validationTest").validate({
        rules: {
            defaults: {
                messages: {required: "<img src='images/required.png' />"}
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).submit();
        }
    })
});
```

But this still doesn't work... any thoughts or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#field').validate({
            rules: {
                f1: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                f1: "<img src='images/icons-coquette/accept.png' />"
            }
        })
    });
```

for all try $.extend

```
        $.extend(
            $.validator.messages, {
            required: "put your message here" //or put <img /> tag
        });
```

Comment: Hey, I just want to set it in 1 place for all the fields... not specific to a field.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. You probably could remove the message inside the jquery.validate.js and put the image tag there, for a dirty sollution. :) I'll search for an better answer

Comment: This is correct: just to clarify, you can put an `img` tag inside of the "put your message here" text.

Comment: I know but you want to be default for all, isn't? See above for the jQuery $.extend utility